How to use .env variables inside .npmrc?
I want to use .env file variables in .npmrc file. Is that possible?
I know we can run export SOME_PRIVATE_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=1234 before run npm install, but I don't want to do that everytime. I want to keep it inside .env.
# .env
SOME_PRIVATE_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=1234

# .npmrc
@some-private-repo:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${SOME_PRIVATE_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}


looks like similar question here

You can try to use npmrc-replace-env
which would generate the .npmrc file for you from .npmrc.config and .env file
